# One who breaks in to show the victim's vulnerability

Tags: single-word-requests

This doesn't necessarily have to be a physical break in, it can also apply to one who creates and distributes a virus that doesn't collect any information or corrupt any files, but alerts the user that they have a virus and should be more careful on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "[white hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_hat_%28computer_security%29)", from the wikipedia link -

> The term "white hat" in Internet slang refers to an ethical computer hacker, or a computer security expert, who specializes in penetration testing and in other testing methodologies to ensure the security of an organization's information systems.

Comment: Note: if the hacker doesn't have permission but is still benevolent in their intentions they may also be called a "grey hat."

Comment: @pavja2 +1 or inmate #0123456789